# Intermittent message "Could not update; currently locked", While inserting record in ACCESS 2000

Tags: ms-access

Below are the Form Properties:

1. Navigation Buttons : Yes
2. Record Lock:   No Lock

Front end, is on the users Local m/c. Which is inserting the record in a Access DB of Network location, on clicking of Navigation buttons, as Table is link to table on Network location.

I am getting this eror message: "Could not update; currently locked";
Some times it works fine.

Can somebody help me on this?
I wasted 3 days, but I did not find any thing, that could help me.

Comment: How many users? Do users have full permissions on the back-end folder? Do you run any code on the form, particularly any code that uses recordsets? Under options, have you set record level or page level locking?

Comment: More then 15 users uses it. It is using "Navigation Buttons". To insert the record and update the record. It is using below query in the "Record Source" Property of Form ----"SELECT DISTINCTROW [File Requests].* FROM [File Requests]; "

Comment: @Remou: Users have the access to Network path, as they are able to use app., but issue is intermittent

Comment: @Remou, As you mentioned to Check under Options:(Tools->option-->Advanced)  But these settings sre specific to local desktop. Do they have something to do with Database on NAS. If it so, please reply. So that i can request all the users, who ever are using this application can change their local settings.

Comment: If you have 15 users, isn't possible that the record is being edited? http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/about-sharing-an-access-database-on-a-network-mdb-HP005240860.aspx

Comment: @Remou: MSDN link you mentioned , they are talking about "You can also set options that control the locking of data and the refreshing of data in a shared database.". Can you please let me know where i can get these optioned. As i setted the form property to 'No Locks'. But The database on NAS, i am not finding any such property.

Comment: No locks is not a good idea. Are you sure that the record is not locked while someone is editing? If it is, then this is the proper behaviour.

Comment: Yes, i am sure. I tell you apication is like: If I orders one letter, it will make an entry to access table. Other user will have  nothing to do with that record. But this new record will be processed for printing of letter, and it's status will be updated to Printed. BUt we are facing this issue, even we are ordering this letter for the first time. I mean there is no entry in DB, we are requesting for the new entry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three places where locking can be set:

1. The back-end database under Tools->Options
2. The front-end, same place
3. The various forms, on the data tab

If you do not think users will often come into conflict, you can set these to No Locks (optimistic locking). If two users try to change the same record, they will get a message.

Page level locking is the default, and is faster. Allen Browne suggests that you do not tick Use record level locking.

Track name autocorrect is an anti-feature and should not be used, except in very specific instances. It causes all sorts of strange problems.

It is nearly always a good idea to compact and repair if odd things are happening.

**Some reading**

Set options for a shared Access database (MDB) http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/set-options-for-a-shared-access-database-mdb-HP005188297.aspx

Page-Level Locking vs. Record-Level Locking http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa189633(v=office.10).aspx

Help Access run faster  http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/help-access-run-faster-HA010235589.aspx

Comment: Please clarify my one doubt. 1st option : Tools-->Option....This setting is not specific to database as When i opens the same NAS mdb in other computer, these settings are different. So my concern is shall i told all the user to have common setting. OR setting the lock property in front end is enough.

Comment: If you have a standard set-up, each user has a copy of a front-end database with links to a back-end database containing the data. Ideally, the front-end database is created by the developer and compiled into an .mde. The developer ensures that all forms etc have the correct settings and arranges that each user has a copy on their desktop. If your set-up demands that each user has control of their own front-end, it would probably be best that they used the same settings. Please be aware that using No Locks can cause confusion when conflicts occur.